# How can some army people sense Lloyd's power level in "Tatoeba Last Dungeon Mae no Mura no Shounen ga Joban no Machi de Kurasu Youna Monogatari"?

Tags: suppose-a-kid-from-the-last-dungeon

The full titles are "Tatoeba Last Dungeon Mae no Mura no Shounen ga Joban no Machi de Kurasu Youna Monogatari" and "Suppose a Kid from the Last Dungeon Boonies Moved to a Starter Town"

In the two episodes so far, Riho Flavin, Merthophan/Meltfan, and Chrome Molibden have shown that they can estimate Lloyd Belladonna's power level at a single glance. This ability is not shared by the Marie (witch) and many other army personnel, apparently including the army man who interviewed Lloyd as part of the entrance exam. Lloyd, himself, can't sense other people's power levels.

What is the canon explanation why some people can sense Lloyd's power level, and why others can't?

Comment: If the anime's only two episodes in, isn't it possible that this will be explained in a future episode?

Comment: The manga has 7 chapters so far, and the LN, 11. Maybe some explanation there?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be limited to characters who have a certain level of combat experience. It does make a lot of sense for people having spent a large amount of time on the battle field, or fighting one on one, to get a "feel" for their opponent strength with a quick glance.